# Is there a way to add some margin between bars in a flot bar chart?

Tags: flot

I've got two bars, one for inbound and one for outbound. They look like this:
[image]

Is there a way I could add some margin between them? Right now the values for them is

```
var d1 = [[0, 1], [3, 7], [6, 12], [9, 17]];
var d2 = [[1, 4], [4, 9], [7, 14], [10, 19]];
```

and as you could see I'm skipping one for each period, but I would also want some margin between :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the barWidth parameter (in the bars object inside the series object inside the options object) to something less than 1.

```
            bars: {
                show: true,
                align: "center",
                barWidth: 0.8,
                fill: true,
                horizontal: true
            }
```